Gnuplot: Warning: empty x range [1.72181e+09:1.72181e+09], adjusting to [1.7046e+09:1.73903e+09]
I must state that this is my first time dealing with gnuplot. I am getting cpu temp via ipmitool and sending it to a file. The data is appended to the file in this format $TIME $CPU1 $CPU2, the time var is TIME=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") in the script that generates the data.
Here is the script im using to plot the data:
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

# Set the output file type and name
set terminal png size 800,600
set output 'cpu_temps_plot.png'

# Set the title and labels
set title "CPU Temperatures Over Time"
set xlabel "Time"
set ylabel "Temperature (°C)"

# Set the x-axis to use time format
#original code
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
set format x "%H:%M\n%m/%d"

# Plot the data
plot "cpu_temps.dat" using 1:2 with lines title "CPU1 Temp", \
     "cpu_temps.dat" using 1:3 with lines title "CPU2 Temp"


When executing the plot script, I get the following error. I have run to the end of my rope
#gnuplot plot_temp.gp 
Warning: empty x range [1.72181e+09:1.72181e+09], adjusting to [1.7046e+09:1.73903e+09]


Here is what the input data looks like:
Here is a few lines of input data:

Time CPU1_Temperature CPU2_Temperature
2024-07-24 12:13 35 43
2024-07-24 12:14 36 44
2024-07-24 12:16 37 44 


Could you please show a few lines of the input data file?

We need to see a few lines of the input data. One thing to try is edit out the year from the data file and see if that alters the behaviour at all. Gnu plot can be fickle and unforgiving so the learning curve is pretty steep.

Input data has been added above.

@terrywhitejr2000 thanks for adding some data. These seem to be the first lines? What are the last lines of your file?

The last line will be equivalent to the last line of the above data. It will be date time and temp

@terrywhitejr2000 well, I meant: what is the actual range of your time data? I cannot reproduce your warning. Other questions: 1. Do you get an output graph? If yes, what does it look like? 2. Is this the complete script or do you maybe have any xrange setting which you don't show here? 3. Which gnuplot version are you running?

So, i was able to get it working. I had to set yrange and and fix the formatting for xrange date and time format. Thank you guys so much!

@terrywhitejr2000 by default the ranges should have autoscale. So, then it looks like you had some more settings active which you did not show here. Please either put your findings into an answer (you can answer your own questions) or delete the question to avoid unanswered questions, but which are answered in the comments.
